# Drop and add linked child node into tree using D3 js

Tags: d3.js

I have a toolbar contains shapes(rect,circle etc.).

I created horizontal tree from json data. Now i want to add more node into tree by drag and drop from shape toolbar.

There is any example or way,while drag from tool and drop on root node, root node automatically create tree link(diagonal) with dropped child node?

Thanks

Comment: This example may help you, https://bl.ocks.org/adamfeuer/042bfa0dde0059e2b288

Comment: Thank You Musakkhir. It's look like same.. but instead of cut from existing tree and drop on node...i need to drop from toolbar.